# AWS CDK Python - Endpoint Configuration type EDGE is not supported in this region

Tags: python, aws-cdk

How to I define a specific API Gateway endpoint configuration for this stack?  I receive the following error when deploying the API gateway resource (*apigw.LambdaRestApi*):  **Endpoint Configuration type EDGE is not supported in this region: us-gov-west-1**.  I found information on the **endpointConfiguration** property to change the endpoint type, but am struggling with how to define this to update the code successfully.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_apigateway as apigw,
)


class CdkworkshopStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        
        # Define Lambda Resource
        my_lambda = _lambda.Function(
            self, 'HelloHandler',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
            code=_lambda.Code.asset('lambda'),
            handler='hello.handler',
        )
        
        apigw.LambdaRestApi(
            self, 'Endpoint', 
            handler=my_lambda,
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just to be clear, you *don't* want EDGE type endpoint configuration? You want REGIONAL, or perhaps PRIVATE?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/LambdaRestApi.html

Judging by this I think you might just do:

```
        apigw.LambdaRestApi(
            self, 'Endpoint', 
            handler=my_lambda,
            endpoint_configuration=EndpointType.REGIONAL
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That is correct.  I was able to update the code just as you recommended and stack deployed successfully.  Thanks.

Comment: np, if you're up to it, feel free to mark my response as the accepted answer